# Convert soap request to http

Tags: web, soap, uri

Lets say i have url

http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx

and soap request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetCountriesAvailable 
xmlns="http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/" />
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

using this, i get the soap response.

But i just want to use url to get soap response. can it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot create a SOAP message without envelope and body as they are required parameters for any message to conform to SOAP standard.